# Is it possible to have a planet made entirely out of water?

Tags: gravity, water, planet

Let's say we had a mechanism of adding unlimited amounts of water at a certain point in space. How much water could we add until the water molecules would turn into something else due to gravity? What would the composition of this "planet" be if we went past that point? Would it be possible to have an Earth-sized blob of water? Would there be ice at the surface and water inside?

Comment: I think those water molecules will turn into something else (water ice) due to vacuum straight away as soon as they are added to a certain point in space. And then sublimate to vapour.

Comment: This is an interesting question but I don't think that it is on-topic here in Space Exploration SE. However, Worldbuilding SE has many water planet questions, including [Could a planet made completely of water exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4969/40033) and [What is the largest I can make my water planet, while remaining within Earth-like parameters?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/146240/40033) and even [A continuous water “planet” ring around a star](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/152747/40033)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about building planets are far too hypothetical for the site. There are some well-received terraforming questions here, but the more hypothetical ones get closed as well. Worldbuilding SE might be a good site for this, but there are several water planet questions there already. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: @LeoS it's an interesting thought. If there was a water atmosphere then the water would stay warm; H2O is a powerful greenhouse gas! So it might be bistable; an ice ball may never sublimate fast enough to maintain a water atmosphere, but if you melt it and evaporate an atmosphere of water [up to the triple point pressure](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17127/12102) then its possible it will stay warm and liquid.

Comment: I was going to lament that the worldbuilding answers don't actually come up with any figures, only of course at the pressure limits of liquid water it is actually noticably compressible and trying to work out the radius and mass of a sphere of compressible material being squished under its own gravitation seems like a right hassle.

Comment: Take a look at the phase diagram of water - in particular the many different "ice-XX" configs that can happen -- and start calculating the pressure at the center of a sphere of water of radius N.  That'll at least get you started.  However I wouldn't be surprised if heat effects take over and the water starts boiling off long before any volume gets pressurized into solid water.

Comment: There is some information of water-rich planets summarized from a more in-depth paper at [this site](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~lzeng/planetmodels.html#h2oplanets) as potential models for some of the exoplanets found by space missions. These models go up to 75% water and talks about the phase transitions. I'm pretty sure I've seen exoplanet mass-radius diagrams with '100% H2O' lines on them but these may be acting as boundary line between the various major classes of exoplanet composition.

Answer (score 1):

**How much water could we add until the water molecules would turn into something else due to gravity?**

It depends on how close this "waterworld" is to its parent star and thus how hot it is. Water has several phases and/or crystalline structures at temperatures and pressures that aren't typical of Earth.

[image: Water Phases by Pressure/Temperature]

**What would the composition of this "planet" be if we went past that point?**

If by what you mean disassociating the water altogether and/or fusing the hydrogen in the water, you're looking at a very metallic star. The smallest hydrogen-burning stars are roughly 14 times the mass of Jupiter though this figure may be higher due to its metallicity.

**What would the composition of this "planet" be if we went past that point?**

Atomic hydrogen, fused helium, and atomic oxygen

**Would it be possible to have an Earth-sized blob of water?**

[Gliese 1214 b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_1214_b) is a candidate object of such a waterworld, though it has a radius of 2.6x earth and 6.5x earth's mass.

**Would there be ice at the surface and water inside?**

Again that would depend on the planet's mass and proximity to its parent star. Europa has a thick layer of ice on its surface and liquid water below, though in warmer areas of a hypothetical solar system, it's perfectly possible to have water on the surface as seen on earth. It should be noted that at higher temperatures or lower surface gravity, water vapor [will escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape) the hypothetical planet.

[image: Gas Escape Velocity by Temperature and Gravity]